# Allow LocalSystem to access PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, access-rights, sspi, local-system-account

I'm trying to configure my PostgreSql database ("mydb") in order to give login rights to the windows "LocalSystem" account.

I've created a user in my database named LocalSystem

```
SQL> CREATE USER LocalSystem;
```

Then, I've tried using SSPI config in pg_hba.conf, but maybe I've misconfigured the configuration line:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    mydb            LocalSystem     127.0.0.1/32            sspi
```

When I run a command using psql, I'm asked to provide a password...which i didn't expect..

EDIT:
I've also tried to map my domain account to a postgres user, using

```
pg_ident.conf
#MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
 postgresname  domain\username         postgresname

pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  host  mydb            postgresname    127.0.0.1/32            sspi
```

Does someone know what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What is the error message you get? Note that `LocalSystem` is the same as `localsystem` in SQL. If you want a case-sensitive name, you need to quote it: `"LocalSystem"` when creating the user.

Comment: When i run a command using psql, I'm asked to provide a password. But LocalSystem doesn't have a password, right? This is a Windows account.

Comment: I've also tried to map my domain account to a postgres user and use sspi authentication..

Comment: It asks for the password of the **Postgres** account, **not** the Windows account. you can set the Postgres password through `ALTER ROLE` or in psql using the `\password` command

Comment: Oh, i didn't understood the SSPI authentication that way. I thought the goal of SSPI was to provide a way to "sync" authentication processes between Windows and Postgres so that Postgres password wouldn't be necessary if the user is actually logged-in in windows.

Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

It asks for the password of the Postgres account, not the Windows account. you can set the Postgres password through ALTER ROLE or in psql using the \password command

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add new mapping line to pg_ident.conf:

   `anyMappingName  "SYSTEM@NT AUTHORITY"   postgresUserName`
2. Add this mapping to all active lines in pg_hba.conf:

   `host  mydb   all    127.0.0.1/32        sspi map=anyMappingName`
3. Then you should connect to postgres db as **postgresUserName** user. I mean you should define Username in your connection string, and also define IntegratedSecurity as TRUE.

For example, postgresUserName can be "LocalSystem" user, that you created in postgres db earlier, or superuser "postgres".